# how to solve array index out of range

Tags: arrays, scala, 2d, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my code below to check if the player is within the range of the field/board, the board is 10by10 so goes from 0-9

```
def al() {
if(field(playerX - 1)(playerY) == false && playerX - 1 >= 0){
  playerX = playerX - 1
  checkBounty();
}
```

So the `field(playerX - 1)(playerY) == false` checks for a wall and I also need it to check if its within the board which is done after the AND operator but I get an error saying Array Index out of range: -1

Comment: Boolean expressions evaluates from left to right, you need to check indices first and after value in array: `playerX - 1 >= 0 && field(playerX - 1)(playerY) == false`. Also, maybe you need to check `playerY`

Comment: please show the method field

Comment: this is how it is: 

//the current grid, a 10x10 field, initially all cells are false (i.e. no walls)
  private var field: Array[Array[Boolean]] = Array.ofDim[Boolean](10, 10)

Comment: Better way to avoid this error. Do not use Arrays and do not access by index. That is not the way to do things in Scala.